# Fetch items before render component

Tags: reactjs, components, fetch

I have code like this below and my question is what can I do to get the products fetched before the components are rendered? I mean in my Panel component I have a .map function which shows an error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" because products were not fetched quickly enough.

```
const Announcments = () => {
  const [announcements, setAnnouncement] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/products", {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      await setAnnouncement(data);
    };
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="announcments">
      <TopNav results={announcements.length} />
      <Panel announcements={announcements} />
      <div className="down-pages-list">
        <PagesList />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

.map function:

```
{announcements.results.map((announcement) => (
          <SingleAnnoun
            price={announcement.price}
            title={announcement.name}
            photo={getPhoto(announcement.images[0].file_name)}
          />
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here isn't that "products were not fetched quickly enough" but rather that your initial state doesn't match what you are attempting to render on the initial render. I.e. `announcements` is initially an empty array (`[]`) but you are attempting to map `announcements.results` which is obviously undefined.

## Solution

Use valid initial state so there is something to initially render.

```
const [announcements, setAnnouncement] = useState({ results: [] });
```

Now `announcements.results` is defined and mappable.

This also assumes, of course, that your `setAnnouncement(data);` state update is also correct. i.e. that your JSON `data` is an object with a `results` property that is an array.

BTW, `setAnnouncement` is a synchronous function so there is nothing to `await` for.